# Django Admin, ValidationError as flash?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I was able to show validation error message in django admin.. using this method

```
class TblSearchCase(models.Model):
top_place_id = models.IntegerField()

def clean(self):
    if self.top_place_id < 0:
        raise ValidationError("place id cannot be negative")
```

like this

[image: django admin validation error]

is there a simple way to make this look like a flash message, without having to edit the template?